# Can a sum of three fifth power of integers be 8?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

With $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z},$ by congruence computation we get that $n= a^5+b^5+c^5$ implies $n \not \equiv  4,5,6,7  \pmod{11} $.

For $a,b,c \in \{-100,-99, \dots , 99, 100\}$, the set of integers $n \in \{0,1,\dots , 99,100 \}$ we get is
$$\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 63, 64, 65, 96 \}$$

The smallest non-obvious solution being $n=12$,

$$13^5 + 16^5 - 17^5 = 12$$

The point is that it is exactly the same for $a,b,c \in \{-10000,-9999, \dots , 9999, 10000\}$, so that we could expect that there is no other natural number $n \le 100$ representable like that. Nevertheless according to what happens for cubes (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/223121/34538)), we could also expect the existence of such representations with large integers. By the congruences above, the smallest natural numbers to look is $n=8$.

*Question:* Can a sum of three fifth power of integers be $8$?

Next we should look to $n = 9,10,11,13,14,19,20,21,22,23,24,28,29, \dots$

Comment: It may be a difficult problem. For instance, it is not known if $33$ can be written as the sum of three cubes: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/

Comment: It looks unlikely that $8$ can be written as the sum of three fifth powers due to Vojta's conjecture, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223156/on-the-mixed-sum-of-three-k-th-powers

Comment: @Jack, I expect he has already seen that, as that was his question. But he should have linked both ways.

Comment: @Sebastian I did a small search and confirmed your results. So I added the smallest non-obvious solution which is $n=12$. I hope it is ok.

Comment: FWIW, $(||a|,|b|,|c|)$ cannot all be prime. $8\equiv 2 \bmod 6; \pm 2^5\equiv \pm 2 \bmod 6; \pm 3^5\equiv \pm 3 \bmod 6; \pm (p\ge 5)^5\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 6$. The desired sum can be $\equiv 2 \bmod 6$ only if $a=2$, or if $a=-2$ and $b=3$. In the first case, $|b|,|c|\ge 5$, with a difference of fifth powers $=40$, which is impossible. In the second case, $c^5=-211$ which is also impossible.